# Display big image in QListWidget

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I want to use `QListWidget` to display big images, e.g. 3508×4961 size in pixels, each list item will display one image. The image is set in a `Qlabel` and the `Qlabel` is set into the `QListWidgetItem` by `setItemWidget()`. When my program is running, the list item cannot display the entire image because the image is too large. It only displays the upper part of an image. When I scroll down, the list item changes to the next image immediately instead of showing the lower part of the current image gradually. Does anyone know how to show the lower part of each image by scrolling?

Here is my code,

```cpp
    QImage *image = new QImage("/home/sk/image1.png");
    QLabel *label = new QLabel;
    label->setPixmap(QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image)));
    QListWidgetItem *ite = new QListWidgetItem;
    auto size = label->sizeHint();
    ite->setSizeHint(label->sizeHint());
    size = ite->sizeHint();
    ui->listWidget->addItem(ite);
    ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(ite, label);

    image = new QImage("/home/sk/image2.png");
    label = new QLabel;
    label->setPixmap(QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image)));
    ite = new QListWidgetItem;
    ite->setSizeHint(label->sizeHint());
    ui->listWidget->addItem(ite);
    ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(ite, label);

    image = new QImage("/home/sk/image3.png");
    label = new QLabel;
    label->setPixmap(QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image)));
    ite = new QListWidgetItem;
    ite->setSizeHint(label->sizeHint());
    ui->listWidget->addItem(ite);
    ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(ite, label);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried changing the [scroll mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#ScrollMode-enum) to **ScrollPerPixel**

**setVerticalScrollMode**

and

**setHorizontalScrollMode**

```
    ui->listWidget->setVerticalScrollMode(QListWidget::ScrollPerPixel);
```

and in order to change the scroll step

```
    ui->listWidget->verticalScrollBar()->setSingleStep(10);
    ui->listWidget->verticalScrollBar()->setPageStep(20);
```

these values will be used for scrolling

Comment: It works. Thank you.